# ¿Que tan seguro es usar LIKE '% %'?

Tags: sql

¿Qué tan seguro es usar **`LIKE`** en consultas SQL, y si no lo es, cómo puedo reforzar su seguridad?

Esto para **evitar Inyecciones SQL**

código:

```
$clasificacion = $mysqli->query("/*" . MYSQLND_QC_ENABLE_SWITCH . "*/" . "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE categoria LIKE '%".$categoria."%' LIMIT 15");

while ($clasificado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clasificacion)) {
    echo $clasificado['nombre_producto'],"<br>";
}
```

Comment: Tu consulta es insegura pero no por usar likes si no por que no usas consultas preparadas

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Comment: No tiene nada que ver eso con la seguridad el LIKE te sirve para buscar/obtener datos similares a tu variable

Comment: little bobby tables https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

Depende bastante de el framework y stack  con el que estes trabajando , si estas , si usas php puede utilizar un ORM que te permita crear consultas de tipo TYPESAFE y evitar que le hagan inyecciones a tu codigo.

TYPESAFE son consultas a la base de datos usando orientacion a objetos.

Cuando trabajaba en PHP solia utilizar un ORM bastante facil llamado  [Medoo](https://medoo.in/) , es simple lijero y te permite crear consultas seguras sin tener que exponer sintaxis SQL.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Cuando realizas consultas de esa manera, lo ideal seria escapar todo aquello que podria considerarse una inyeccion sql para eso podrias utilizar

`mysqli_real_escape_string`

2.- Y escapar todo lo que llegue a tu servidor y pueda comprometer tu base de datos

```
$categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['categoria']);
```

3.- En el ejemplo anterior estamos escapando lo que viene por el metodo `$_POST` y lo estamos almacenando en la variable `$categoria`

4.- La variable `$categoria` ahora si podrias pasarla en tu consulta como la estas realizando.

5.- O como dice @BetaM podrias considerar utilizar consultas preparadas

Fuentes:

[mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)